# Entity Framework returns wrong data after execution of two similar queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two similar queries, the first one:

```
var activatedSerialNumbers = (from activation in entities.Activations
                              where !canceledActivationsIds.Contains(activation.Id)
                              where activation.CustomerId == customerId
                              join licenseConfiguration in entities.LicenseConfigurations
                                              on activation.Id equals licenseConfiguration.ActivationId
                              where licenseConfiguration.ProductId == productId
                              join activatedSerialNumber in entities.ActivatedSerialNumbers
                                              on activation.Id equals activatedSerialNumber.ActivationId
                             where deactivatedSams.All(dsn => dsn.ToLower() != 
                                              activatedSerialNumber.Name.ToLower())
                             select new SamWithLicense
                             {
                                     Name = activatedSerialNumber.Name,
                                     Features = licenseConfiguration.LicenseFeatures
                             }).ToList();
```

The second:

```
var activationsForSam = (from activation in entities.Activations
                        where !canceledActivationsIds.Contains(activation.Id)
                        where activation.CustomerId == customerId
                        let activatedSerialNumbers = activation.ActivatedSerialNumbers
                                                    .Select(sn => sn.Name.ToLower())
                        where activatedSerialNumbers.Contains(loweredSn)
                        join licenseConfiguration in entities.LicenseConfigurations
                                             on activation.Id equals activatedProduct.ActivationId
                        select new SamWithLicense
                        {
                                   Name = selectedSerialNumber,
                                   Features = licenseConfiguration.LicenseFeatures
                        }).ToList();
```

In some situations I execute them one after another and in most cases it works fine, but somethimes - not. In the result of second query **Counter** takes from another row:

*Visual Studio - Quick watch*
[image]

*SQL Management Studio* 
[image]

I guess it's a matter of a EF cache or smth, but don't know how to fix it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you are joining the Activation Id (PK) to LicenseConfigurations ActivationId (FK)

```
join licenseConfiguration in entities.LicenseConfigurations
on activation.Id equals licenseConfiguration.ActivationId
```

in your second query, it looks like you are joining on a value defined outside of the query "activatedProduct"

```
join licenseConfiguration in entities.LicenseConfigurations
on activation.Id equals activatedProduct.ActivationId
```